# Steps for back propagation of convolutional layer in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-network, backpropagation

Imagine I have the following layers in a CNN:

***Conv-layer 1 (without reLU) [3 filters @ 1x3x3]*** =>
**ReLU-layer 1** =>
**Maxpooling-layer 1 [2x2]**

***Conv-layer 2 (without reLU) [10 filters @ 3x4x4]*** =>
**ReLU-layer 2** =>
**Maxpooling-layer 2 [2x2]**

What I know is that, when "deriving" the **Maxpooling-layer**, the maximum value of that pooling has the value of 1 (because that value is the only one that is affecting the result of the CNN), and the other values take the value of 0.

After this step, I have the reLU-layer, where the derivative of the reLU-layer is 0 when x <= 0, and 1 when x > 0.

And in the last step, I have the Conv-layer, but I don't know how to calculate the derivative. *How do I calculate the whole delta for that specific weight?*

If there is a way to calculate the gradients of those weights using matrix notation, please let me know.

### Notation

The matrix notation that I use is the following: [number of filters - depth - rows - columns]. For example, when I say [3 filters - 1 x 3 x 3] I mean that I have 3 filters with depth 1, 3 rows and 3 columns (depth is "equivalent" to "channels").

**Steps in Conv layer, using my notation**

Imagine I have an input **X** with shape **[depth:1, rows: 28, columns: 28]**

Then, I have the conv-layer, where I have **3 filters (you can call the filter as W)** with shape **[depth:1, rows:3, columns:3]**

So, what I do is, using 1 filter a time, convolve input X , so the resulting matrix has the following shape => **[depth:1, rows: 26, columns: 26] (this is the result of convolving 1 filter)**. So, when I do the convolution using the 3 filters, the resulting matrix is shaped [**depth:3**, rows: 26, columns: 26].

After this, I apply ReLU to each value of the resulting matrix (the 3x26x26 matrix), and then apply non-overlapping maxpooling with a window of 2 rows x 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Extra Note: The matrix notation that I use is the following: [number of filters - depth - rows - columns]. For example, when I say [3 filters - 1 x 3 x 3] I mean that I have 3 filters with depth 1, 3 rows and 3 columns (depth is "equivalent" to "channels").

**Steps in Conv layer:**

Imagine I have an input **X** with shape **[depth:1, rows: 28, columns: 28]**

Then, I have the conv-layer, where I have **3 filters (you can call the filter as W)** with shape **[depth:1, rows:3, columns:3]**

So, what I do is, using 1 filter a time, convolve input X , so the resulting matrix has the following shape => **[depth:1, rows: 26, columns: 26] (this is the result of convolving 1 filter)**. So, when I do the convolution using the 3 filters, the resulting matrix is shaped [**depth:3**, rows: 26, columns: 26].

After this, I apply ReLU to each value of the resulting matrix (the 3x26x26 matrix), and then apply non-overlapping maxpooling with a window o 2 rows x 2 columns.

If there is any doubt of what I explained, please comment me.

Note: I'm editing my own answer beacuse I don't have 50 reputation for doing comments.

Comment: I know, the problem occured when I wrote the question and asked it as a guest, and not when logged in :( I was trying to edit the question but I can't

Comment: Now I have transferred this into the question, the site can delete your "answer" here. When I ask for this to happen, there might be an automated comment explaining the rule that is being applied.